# My app keeps getting crash reports in google play, but I cannot reproduced the crash

Tags: android

I'm getting daily crash reports from Google Play.  I'm running out of ideas and wondering if there is any tutorials or something on how to find and fix bugs from google plays stack report.
I have done the following

1. Bought one of the devices it is crashing on, Galaxy tab.  Tried to crash it, could not get it to crash.  Tied to have a lot of apps running in background still did not crash.
2. put try catch around all my code where the catch would bring up a generic memory low warning message (ie this really slowed down the app).
   Checked all my return values.

From the stack report, I'm assuming it is crashing somewhere in onTouchEvent methed in my cPuzzleView class.
Any help would be GREAT

```
stack
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fairhvaenapps.toddpuzzlefree.cPuzzleView.onTouchEvent(cPuzzleView.java:653)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1559)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2478)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2059)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7560)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$1.doDispatch(ViewRootImpl.java:338)
at com.lge.view.TouchEventFilter.dispatchFilteredTouchEvent(TouchEventFilter.java:131)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3333)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3255)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4418)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4397)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4506)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4468)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4525)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is on `cPuzzleView.java` line 653?

Comment: HI the line at 6537 is  if (MyShapes.AnimationRunning)
       return true; does this mean that MyShapes is null??????

Comment: Possibly. Take a look at how you're instantiating whatever `MyShapes` is (for convention, if that's an instance, it should be named `myShapes`), and see if there's any way that it could return null. If you're resolving a drawable, is it possible that the drawable does not exist for some configuration?